# Why can android only send binary data to a FTP server?

Tags: java, android, ftp

I have an simple understanding question: Why can I only send Binary Data from Android to a FTP server? I am currently learning it and now I understood it. With ByteArrayInputStream I am converting my string into bytes to send it binary. But why binary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a digital computer, all data are binary.

Are you talking about a lack of the "ASCII" mode that some FTP clients support? Those have always been problematic in the way they tend to corrupt data. Making an exact copy, without alterations, is a lot safer.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is binary in the computer world.